# Subprocess error dealing with "ls" argument in call() function

Tags: python, subprocess

I am new to python, and I want to know what went wrong with this line of instruction. 
This line of code was used in the example for `subprocess` in Python's documentation:

```
subprocess.call(["ls", "-l"])
```

and it basically returned:

```
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Python believes that "ls" is a file rather than an argument. Is there a way this can be fixed?

Comment: ls is not a command native to Windows.

Answer (score 3):

Is it necessary to call the `ls` (or `dir`) command? in Python, you can list a directory's files using [`os.listdir(path)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir), which will be much easier to implement!

Regarding your question: you're trying to call the `ls` command, which is native to Unix-like systems. In Windows, you have to use `dir` instead, as shown in Ignacio's answer.

Comment: Of course it's not necessary. But it is a decent example (when you use a command found on your OS).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Use <s>`["dir", "/w"]`</s> `['ipconfig', '/all']` instead.

Comment: Is `dir` an internal (built-in) command in cmd.exe? Can built-in command be executed without `shell=True`?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: It would appear that it cannot.